# Google Calendar API: HTML tags displayed in Calendar Invite email preview (Gmail App) for GCal Events containing HTML tags in Description

Tags: html, gmail, google-calendar-api

We are making use of the Google Calendar API in order to create Google Calendar Events on our users' Calendars programmatically. In order for the description's formatting to be consistent, we make use of HTML tags, which are supported as per the [GCal API docs](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert):

> description            string                         Description of the event. **Can contain HTML.** Optional.

The HTML renders perfectly fine on the Event in GCal itself as well as upon opening the Calendar Invite email on Gmail. The preview also displays properly on the Gmail website when accessed from a PC/Laptop.

[Email Preview on PC/Laptop Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iowIZ.png)

The issue only arises on the Gmail App on mobile, and when Gmail is opened on browsers from your mobile device (both Android and iPhone).

[Email Preview on Mobile App & Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SyDS.jpg)

Is there any request parameter that we can use to ensure that this does not occur? Or maybe a setting that can be toggled? If this is purely a bug with the Gmail Mobile App, is there any temporary workaround that can be used to hide the HTML from the email preview, until Google fixes it?

I have tried searching for posts that have encountered similar issues to this, but there don't seem to be any. None of the solutions I have come across apply to this scenario.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!